# Do all smart cards support Java Card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I'm trying to get into smart card development using Java Card and I'm a little bit confused on which smart cards are suitable.

1. Do all smart cards support Java Card or do I need to look for some specific models?
2. Do the cards come with the JCRE pre-installed or do I need to install it myself?

For example, if I were to order something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001391460511.html) (AliExpress Link), would it be suitable? What would I need to do with it before being able to upload applets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not all card understand java, the two major groups are:

1. Java cards
2. Native cards

The latter ones need an entirely different approach, since you don't load any code, but all is present as part of its operating system. So it boils down to "just add files, keys (and possibly other objects as well)".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please clarify just a few more things: 

1. When ordering a smart card, does the description explicitly need to say that this is a Java Card or is that a default assumption? 

2. Is the initialization/ATR step already done on Java Cards?

3. Is the JCRE already installed on Java Cards or do I need to do it myself? 

4. For the Native Cards — can I program them in Assembly or is the hardware proprietary?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @Vadim: your additional questions in the comment suggest, that your question is much broader than originally appearing. From my point of view it is now significantly too broad and I suggest that you invest some time learning the basics. General rule: you can't program native cards in any way if not stated differently. I never understood the idea of putting stuff (beyond communication parameters) into the ATR - no room there, and zero resistance against fakes.